# Return a double pointer in JNI

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I want return a pointer to a double array in JNI, and then, use this values in Java's code. So i did this:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing_prueba_1nativa(
        JNIEnv * env, jclass, jlong retorno, jbyteArray data, jint lenbytes) {

//PROCESS

long dirt;
dirt=(long)d_est;
    return(dirt);




}
```

In my java funcition:

```
public void prueba(byte[] data, int lenbytes) {

        prueba=prueba_nativa(retorno, data, lenbytes);


    }
```

So now, How can I acess to my values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either create additional functions to access the array on the native side, exposing them to Java.  Or you can create a jDoubleArray within your native code, and return that to Java.

```
const double * arrayPtr = (const double  *)&yourDoubleArray;
jint lengthOfArray = 0; //Fill dynamically with the length of your native double array.

jdoubleArray doubleArray = (*env)->NewDoubleArray(env, lengthOfArray);
(*env)->SetDoubleArrayRegion( env, doubleArray, 0, 16, arrayPtr);

return doubleArray;
```